# How to enable gstreamer for Firefox 25.0 Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: firefox, 13.10, gstreamer

i try to make a Javascript where I need to test the ability of playing "video/mp4".

I do that with:

```
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.canPlayType('video/mp4');
```

But my Firefox (Version 25.0 / Ubuntu 13.10) returns empty string.

According the Bug I opend on bugzilla: 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=934947

(second comment)

I need to enable gstreamer.

But I dont't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

O.K. found it out my self.
Answer:

Go to

```
about:config
```

(Say yes to warranty warning). Search for gstreamer and change enabled/fals to enabled/true

Thats it.

Comment: This also worked for the SoundCloud playback problem I was having. Thanks for replying to your own question with this solution. :)